# Django Translation Don't Work

Tags: python, django

Try to translate block this block and load i18n:

```
{% load i18n %}

<p>{% trans "Welcome to our page" %}</p>

{% language 'ru' %}
    <p>{% trans "Welcome to our page" %}</p>
{% endlanguage %}
```

settings.py

```
SE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('ru', _('Russian')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
 TEMPLATES = [ {     

             'context_processors': [
                 'django.template.context_processors.i18n',

MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]
```

.po

```
msgid "Welcome to our page"
msgstr "Приветствую вас!"

#: project/settings.py:172
msgid "English"
msgstr "Английский"

#: project/settings.py:173
msgid "Russian"
msgstr "Русский"
```

mo.

```
Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: 
POT-Creation-Date: 2016-10-10 19:24+0000
PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE
Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>
Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>
Language: 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
 Английский Русский Приветствую вас!
```

urls.py

```
import os

from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('account_management.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

But result is:

Welcome to our page
Welcome to our page

I used this doc
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/

Maybe I forgot something?

Comment: Can you show your _urls.py_?

Comment: @vishes_shell Updated

Answer (score 0):

So what is going on, is that you have just ordinary urls, when you needed `i18n_patterns`,

So, change your urls to

```
import os

from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^', include('account_management.urls')),  # put here urls that you need to translate
)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

The docs can be found here [`i18n_patterns`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.conf.urls.i18n)

Comment: Unfortunately, just the same.

Comment: @ vishes_shell Three times.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}` tag which updates the `LANGUAGE_CODE` setting. See [how-django-discovers-language-preference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference).

```
{% load i18n %}

    <p>{% trans "Welcome to our page" %}</p>

{% language 'ru' %}
    {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
    <p>{% trans "Welcome to our page" %}</p>
{% endlanguage %}
```

Hope this helps.